# TypeError: len() of unsized object

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, random-forest, text-classification

I am trying random forest classifier from sklearn, when i want to print the classifier report, it is give me an error.

This was the code :

```
randomforestmodel = RandomForestClassifier()
randomforestmodel.fit(train_vectors, data_train['label'])
predict_rfmodel = randomforestmodel.predict(test_vectors)

print("classification with randomforest")
print(metrics.classification_report(test_vectors, predict_rfmodel))
```

And the error was like this :

```
    classification with randomforest
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-f976cec884e4> in <module>()
      1 print("classification with randomforest")
----> 2 print(metrics.classification_report(test_vectors, predict_rfmodel))

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py in classification_report(y_true, y_pred, labels, target_names, sample_weight, digits, output_dict, zero_division)
   2108     """
   2109 
-> 2110     y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
   2111 
   2112     if labels is None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py in _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
     83     """
     84     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)
---> 85     type_true = type_of_target(y_true)
     86     type_pred = type_of_target(y_pred)
     87 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py in type_of_target(y)
    308 
    309     # Invalid inputs
--> 310     if y.ndim > 2 or (y.dtype == object and len(y) and not isinstance(y.flat[0], str)):
    311         return "unknown"  # [[[1, 2]]] or [obj_1] and not ["label_1"]
    312 

TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're providing the test instances *features* (`test_vectors`) instead of the true test instances *labels* to `classification_report`.

As [per the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html), the first parameter should be:

> **y_true**: 1d array-like, or label indicator array / sparse matrix.
>
> Ground truth (correct) target values.

Comment: It worked, thanks.
I have change 
`print(metrics.classification_report(test_vectors, predict_rfmodel))`
with 
`print(classification_report(data_test['label'], predict_rfmodel))`